# How can I establish a connection between an AS/400 server and Hadoop, and move data?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sqoop

How do you get data/tables from db2 on an AS/400 server to a Hadoop filesystem? How do you establish a connection between the AS/400 server and a Hadoop file system?

I know that we can get data/tables from MySQL server data to a Hadoop filesystem using SQOOP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that DB2 has native connector in Sqoop, so I would recommend similar way as you're moving data from MySQL (e.g. using JDBC interface).

Answer (score 0):

SQOOP uses a JDBC connector to interact with databases. You can use the JT400 Java library ( http://jt400.sourceforge.net/ ) for the JDBC driver.